# The LEGO house cipher

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual

*This is a true story...* Today I am at home looking after my daughter who is off sick from school. We spent some time this morning playing with LEGO and built a house. Not just any house though - because somehow among our brick choices we've managed to encode the name of the street on which you'll find this house...

So based off the following picture, tell me:

> **What is the name of the street, as indicated by the sign out front?**

[image]

<sup>*With apologies to those with colour-blindness who may not be able to view the image correctly... The 10 coloured bricks within the sign are (from L to R): green, light blue, brown, lime green, clear, pink, navy blue, sky blue, yellow, orange.*</sup>

Comment: This puzzle is partly inspired by [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92086/why-is-my-husband-sending-this-photograph-and-to-whom/92434)

Comment: Nice puzzle! Hope your daughter feels better soon.

Comment: Haha! Thanks @hexomino - this is day 5 (of chickenpox) so hopefully not too long to go before she starts to feel brighter... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> BRICK LANE

Green:

> This is binary (00100) or Bacon's Cipher (aabaa) for **E**

Light Blue:

> Per @hexomino, if you look at the group of nonmetals on the periodic table, you get CNO (6, 7, 8) and PS (15, 16), so the missing letter is **N**
>
> I still think it just looks like a chunky/blocky letter N (from lower left trace up, right, down, right, up).

Brown (FINALLY):

> Scrooge is holding his brown canes like the Flag semaphore for **A**

Lime Green:

> The 12th letter of the alphabet is **L**

Clear:

> Just a space

Pink:

> This looks like the **K** block from a normal pigpen cipher

Navy Blue:

> I think this is just the letter **C**, as the 3 nearby letters (O, P, S) look like a different color

Sky Blue:

> There are 9 sky blue bricks, and **I** is the 9th letter of the alphabet.  Thanks @mihomir!!

Yellow:

> The windows look like Braille for the letter **R**

Orange:

> The orange bricks look like Morse Code for the letter **B**

That produces:

> **ENAL KCIRB**
> Since the arrow points right to left, switch the order to **BRICK LANE**

Comment: A brilliant start :) There is stronger logic to support the N (I wouldn't say it looks like one...) - use something you haven't used yet (but have mentioned...). Keep looking for the brown and sky blue (don't overthink that one...). And yes, as per the final letter I was thinking [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher)...

Comment: On reflection, I see what you mean now about the light blue resembling a letter! Not intended - there is stronger logic, as I say ^

Comment: @Stiv Ah, hadn't thought of applying pork.  I modified the answer a bit, but I'm still not clear on light blue, and I'm more likely *under*thinking the sky blue.  =)

Comment: @hagfy Regarding sky blue - rot13 V vf gur avagu yrggre bs gur nycunorg?

Comment: The colour you think is brown is not (it's a dark red) - look elsewhere! And listen to @mihomir! :) Light blue requires the knowledge tag...

Comment: @mihomir Wow, so you proved me wrong, I actually *was* overthinking sky blue!  Thanks!

Comment: Not the chimney either - that's *light* brown! :) You're so close to wrapping this all up...

Comment: @Stiv ARGH, I know the brown now.  Just stuck on light blue then.

Comment: @hagfy I think Scrooge's canes are brown. And that should give you a way to get something from them.

Comment: Think about somewhere you might find those 5 letters (including the missing one) in that exact layout... That's the last clue I shall give! I'll let the community take over from here if you still don't know :)

Comment: @Stiv FIVE letters?  Is the navy blue a double-clue?  I'm gonna have to think on that (aka wait for mihomir to figure it out).

Comment: @hagfy For light blue look at the rot13(crevbqvp gnoyr)

Comment: And that's a wrap! Well done :) Thanks for completing it. The checkmark is yours!